# Any way to get a fully typed Class reference?

Tags: java

`List.class` is of type `Class<List>`. Note that List is referenced as a raw type. Since passing in a class is often used in generics method to determine the type parameter, is there a way to get a class object that fully specifies the type, such as `Class<List<Integer>>` or event `Class<List<?>>`?

Answer (score 8):

No. At runtime, `List<Integer>`, `List<Object>` and `List` are the same type, due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: I understand type erasure. I am not asking for an explanation of why List.class referenced raw List.

Comment: And what could Class<List<Integer>> reference, since at runtime, List<Integer> doesn't exist?

Comment: The same thing as Class<List>.

Comment: Isn't it exactly what's happening?

Comment: Since Class object is used to pin type parameter in many generic methods. This means that inferred type of those methods is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

No (see JB's answer), however, you can use class.getTypeParameters() to find out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters()

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write a utility method for a particular parameterized class, such as a List.

```
public static <X> Class<List<X>> typedListClass( Class<X> type )
{
    return (Class) List.class;
}
```

Then this works fine:

```
Class<List<Integer>> cl = typedListClass( Integer.class )
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already touched on the nature of erasures, etc... so I'll just include an example of how to get the reference:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Class<List<Integer>> cls = (Class<List<Integer>>)(Class)List.class;
```

Not the prettiest thing.  But first you need to completely erase the type of `List.class` to just `Class`, then you can cast it to `Class<List<Integer>>`.  At runtime its equivalent to the erased version of `Class cls = List.class`, but you'll get the compile time checks whenever you use the `cls` variable.

The `@SuppressWarnings` is required since you're doing bad things and you want to tell the compiler that you know that you are.  Just how bad?  Well... you have to be careful with the approach since you could have *any* class on the right-hand side, and the compiler won't care.  You'll find the problems at runtime then. :)